# Python ByteToHex Java Conversion

Tags: java, python, converters

Hey I have this ByteToHex converter in python and I wanted to convert it into java and I have no idea how all my attempts have failed so I've come here.. Here the code

```
def ByteToHex( byteStr ):

    return ' '.join( [ "%02X" % ord( x ) for x in byteStr ] )
```

I just wanna know how to do that in a java method

**EDIT**

I have this string I send over a socket and its this

```
String hexStr = "\\x7E\\x00\\x0C\\x01\\x00\\xA5\\xBD\\x00\\x7E\\x01\\x00\\x40\\x2D\\x00\\x3F\\x71";
```

Then I tried to write a method that jsut converts the string so it would look something like this.

```
7E 00 16 A1 C5 DD 39 02 7E 00 01 E7 2D 0A 00 23 41 1B 6C 11 B9 B9 B9 BA 3B E8
```

Just a simple string into an array with no 'x' and no '\' I tried doing it like this in java...

```
public byte[] ByteToHex(String hexx) {
    byte [] b;
    hexx.replace("\\", "");

    for (int i = 0; i < hexx.length(); i++) {
        hexx.replace("\\", "");
        b[i] = char(i) + b.add(i +1);
    }
}
```

But thats clearly not right and I just cant figure it out.

Comment: Well, tell us (as an edit to your question) what your attempts were and in what way they failed.

Comment: Updated @RealSkeptic sorry about the lack of info I didn't think it would be needed because its such a failed attempt

Comment: So you want to convert a string that has "\\x" to the same string without the "\\x"? Then you work only with strings (and `StringBuilder` perhaps). Why involve a byte array? But this is really not related to your python code, which I believe takes a byte array and converts it to a hex string.

Comment: Yes. No the python code converts it into a list and then from there I make it a string and cut it down into only 8 bits and since java doesnt have "bytestring" im just gonna use an array you cut off the required peice.. if you understand what im trying to say.. aha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

Just going back to my old questions and answering them.

```
public static String ByteToHex (String hex) {
    return hex.replace("\\x", " ");
}
```